# Wordpress 3 latest blog posts in order of left to right instead of right to left

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to display the 3 latest blog posts. At the moment the blog posts are appearing right to left instead of left to right.

```
<?php $counter = 3;
   $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
   $recentPosts->query("showposts=3");

?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
<div class="box<?php echo $counter--; ?>">
```

How do I make the latest blog appear first? By first I mean on the left instead of the right. Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can just add `float: right` to you div. That will visually do what you want.

Comment: I have post one answer let me know if its works for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
$recentPosts->query("showposts=3&order=DESC");
```

read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more information about queries

Answer (score 0):

just edit

```
$recentPosts->query("showposts=3, order=DESC");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Unfortunately this didn't make a change at all. Posts still remain in the same order..